# Are bind parameters supported for property names when querying JSON in Snowflake?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some JSON stored in a table in a column named `ROW_DATA` in my Snowflake database like so:

```json
{"Test Column 1": "abc", "Test Column 2": "def", "Test Column 3": "ghi"}
```

I am trying to query the JSON using Snowflake's built in JSON Data Parsing (described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-query)) with a parameter set to the JSON property name like so:

```sql
SELECT ROW_DATA::myParameter::string FROM TableName
```

Where `:myParameter` is a parameter I am binding to in my C# code using the [Snowflake Connector](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net). Unfortunately, this keeps resulting in an error:

> Unsupported data type 'MYPARAMETER'

I've also tried using question mark annotation for the parameter:

```sql
SELECT ROW_DATA:(?)::string FROM TableName
```

In this case, a different error occurs saying "unexpected character ) and ?", leading me to believe its not parsing it correctly.

The C# sharp code I am using is:

```cs
string columnSql = "SELECT ROW_DATA::myParameter::string FROM TableName";

DbCommand colValCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
colValCommand.CommandText = columnSql;

DbParameter myParameter = colValCommand.CreateParameter();
nameParam.DbType = DbType.String;
nameParam.Value = "Test Column 1";
nameParam.ParameterName = "myParameter";
colValCommand.Parameters.Add(myParameter);

using (DbDataReader reader = await colValCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())  //Error here
{
   ...
}
```

Is using parameters for this use case supported with Snowflake and/or the .NET Connector for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parametrize field name [GET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get) function should be used:

> Extracts a value from an ARRAY or an OBJECT (or a VARIANT that contains an ARRAY or OBJECT).

```
SELECT GET(ROW_DATA, ?)::STRING 
FROM TableName
```